# There is a similiar "method" in AngularJS like RenderSection in Asp.Net MVC?

Tags: angularjs

I have an issue in AngularJS when I'm trying to use ui-view.
The controller only stay visible if I declare the script inside the full page.
If I need to do this with every controller that I create, I am going to have a lot of controllers inside of my index page instead of a single controller inside of a page.
In Asp.net MVC, I can use the RenderSection function.
There is my code:

Index.html

```
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <script src="Scripts/angular.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/angular-ui-router.min.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/venus.js"></script>
    <script src="Scripts/controllers/conteudoController.js"></script>
</head>
<body ng-app="VenusApp">
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-md-3">
                <p class="lead">Shop Name</p>
                <div class="list-group">
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Category 1</a>
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Category 2</a>
                    <a href="#" class="list-group-item">Category 3</a>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-md-9" ui-view="">
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
```

and my second page is only a html table.

Sorry for any issue, but this is my first post in stackoverflow.

Comment: Yes, there is. It's called directive transclusion.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its seems like your problem is that even though you do not require some other controller, you still need to inject in the main index.html prior to that controller is even used right?

In Angularjs you can use `$ocLazyLoad` module which will let you load the controller only when it is required.

You will configure which controller is require when, while you define your routing configration in angularjs config.

This is how it can be done.

```
  $stateProvider
           .state('login', {
               url: '/login',
               controller: 'LoginCtrl',
               templateUrl: 'views/login.html',
               resolve: {
                   loadMyFiles: function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                       return $ocLazyLoad.load({
                           name: 'Myapp',
                           files: [
                           'scripts/controller/login.js'
                           ]
                       })
                   }
               }
           }).state('reset', {
               url: '/reset/token/:token',
               controller: 'ResetCtrl',
               templateUrl: 'views/reset.html',
               resolve: {
                   loadMyFiles: function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                       return $ocLazyLoad.load({
                           name: 'Myapp',
                           files: [
                           'scripts/controller/reset.js'
                           ]
                       })
                   }
               }
           }).state('verify', {
               url: '/verify',
               controller: 'VerifyCtrl',
               templateUrl: 'views/verify.html',
               resolve: {
                   loadMyFiles: function ($ocLazyLoad) {
                       return $ocLazyLoad.load({
                           name: 'Myapp',
                           files: [
                           'scripts/controller/verify.js'
                           ]
                       })
                   }
               }
           })
```

Not only your controller JS , you can even lazy load the css.This will help you reduce loading tons of JS and css all in index.html.

**Note : I am not using ng-route ,instead i am using ui-router.Above code is ui-router + $ocLazyLoad**